# Angular JS doesn't update select and input from date calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Angular JS and Bootstrap and I want to update the input of a datepicker calendar and a select from a function.

The values are updated but I can't see these on their correspondent inputs.

We can say that I'm updating the model but not the view. If I update the model from the view everything works fine but not to the contrary.

In the same form, if I update a a checkBox making clic ... Surprise. The select and the datepicker calendar are updated.

How can I update the view from my model and see this update?

**Edit 1:**

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model = "searchPAI.sistemaSelected" class="form-control" ng-options="sistema.nombreSistema for sistema in listSistemas">
</select>
<p class = "input-group" ng-controller = "dpFechaDesde">
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" uib-datepicker-popup = "{{format}}" name = "dtInicio" ng-model = "dateFrom" is-open = "popup1.opened" ng-change = "change2()"
    min-date = "minDate" max-date = "maxDate" datepicker-options = "dateOptions" close-text = "Cerrar" clear-text = "Borrar" now-text = "Hoy" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>                     
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.searchPAI.sistemaSelected = $scope.listSistemas[id];
$scope.$on("updateFechaDesde", function(){
        $scope.dateFrom = publicDPFactory.date;
        MyVar.data.dtFrom = publicDPFactory.date;
        console.log("publicDPFactory.date: " + publicDPFactory.date);
        console.log("scope.dateFrom: " + $scope.dateFrom);
});
```

I remember, everything works fine if I update the model from the view.

**Edit 2:**

More surprises! How I said previously, I update the value from the model and I can't see these on the view.

[image]

But, if I make a clic over "SI" ... Surprise!!! I can see the values updated on the view. You can see right now the select and the datapicker updated.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code?  What are you working with?  Are you working with a datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!!!

To update the view from the model, after updated the model you have to call to ...

```
$scope.$apply();
```

And right now you can see all the changes!!!

[image]

How can you see, I don't need to make any clic over any other component from the form to see my values updated in the model on the view.